# Indexing a GeoJSON file to solr with many features

Tags: java, solr, geojson, spatial

I'm trying to index a GeoJSON file with over 550 features but solr is grouping it in a weird way.
I need to map an ID to each feature and my result is this one result:

```
"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "start":"2688",
      "rows":"1",
      "_":"1615400339792"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2692,"start":2688,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "type":["FeatureCollection"],
        "features.type":["Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          "Feature",
          ....
          "Feature"],
        "features.properties.main_id":[1,
          1,
          2,
          2,
          3,
          3,
          4,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          6,
          7,
          7,
          8,
          ...
          8],
          "features.geometry.type":["Point",
          "Point",
          "Polygon",
          "Polygon",
          "Point",
          "Point",
          "Point",
          "Point",
          "Point",
          "Point",
          ...
          "Point"],
           "features.geometry.coordinates":["39.166666666667",
          "-6.2833333333333",
          "39.1775",
          "-6.2838888888889",
          ...
           "-17.0"],
        "id":"dbb98ccd-616f-4c69-a793-910842871e8d",
        "_version_":1693870645365964800}]
  }}
```

But what I want is one result per feature with its ID like here in the indexed .geojson file:

```
 {
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [ {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
      "main_id" : 1
    },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ 39.166666666667, -6.2833333333333 ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
      "main_id" : 1
    },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ 39.1775, -6.2838888888889 ]
    }
  }, 
  ...
  {
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
      "main_id" : 596
    },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -149.89972222222, -17.486666666667 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

I tried the following commands to index the data.geojson file:

```
java -Dc=myCore-jar -Dtype=application/json -Dauto=yes  .\example\exampledocs\post.jar C:\Users\User\DBCon\data.geojson

java -Dauto=yes -Durl="http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/update?format=geojson" -Dtype=application/json -jar .\example\exampledocs\post.jar C:\Users\User\DBCon\data.geojson
```

I'm working with Solr 8.8 on my Windows10 Client. JTS Version is 1.15.0. and the schema configuration for spatialdata is

```
...
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
...
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.001" distanceUnits="kilometers"/>
...
```

I'm grateful for any tips!

Comment: Have you looked at https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html - in particular the `f` and the `split` parameter?